# How to serialize class and his objects

Tags: c#

I have an Class structure like this:

```
class A { 
   Dictionary<UInt64, B> listB;
   method1(){}
   methodN(){}
}

class B {       

   Dictionary<UInt32, C> listC;
   Dictionary<UInt32, E> listE;
   List<F> listF;
   method1(){}
   methodN(){}
}

class C { 
   Dictionary<UInt32, D> listD;
   method1(){}
   methodN(){}
}

class D { 
   method1(){}
   methodN(){}
}   

class E { 
   method1(){}
   methodN(){}
}    

class F { 
   method1(){}
   methodN(){}
}
```

Class A is the main Class, and B is a sub class of A. All other classes are sub class of B.

I want to serialize class A with all sub Classes.

How can I serialize these Objects?

Thank You!

Comment: You could use objects that can be serialized (`Dictionary` objects are inherently not.) Also, look in to the [`SerializableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx).

Comment: Who voted down and why? Please write a comment if you downvote. This is a Site, where we ask questions. Be fair.

Comment: @Vural Acar : which serialization are you want to use? XML/Binary?

Comment: I will send the serialized objects to the clients per socket connection. I think the binary mode is more suitable for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you said you want to do it over sockets, probably something like this:

```
public void SerializeObject(NetworkStream stream, ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize)
{
   varbFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   bFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
   stream.Close();
}

public ObjectToSerialize DeSerializeObject(NetworkStream stream)
{
   ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize;
   var bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   objectToSerialize = (ObjectToSerialize)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
   stream.Close();
   return objectToSerialize;
}
```

edit: *note: code is untested. it probably needs some modifications depending on your stream and such*

And like Brad commented, give all your classes the SerializableAttribute.

```
[Serializable]
class A { 
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `BinaryFormatter`? If the client has exactly the same binaries, it's the easiest way to get them across.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx